# Backbone collection boolean flip

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

When I am listening for a change event for a boolean attribute of a model in the collection, how do I handle the event to toggle to turn the bool off on all the other models in the collection.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you listening for the event? Paste some code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
// in your model
yourModel.on('change:yourBooleanAttribute', yourCollection.setAllButCurrent);

// and in your collection
setAllButCurrent: function(changedModel, value, options) {
    // here you can iterate through `this.models` and for each model 
    // if it's `id` differ from changedModel id, change it's `yourBooleanAttribute`
    // to the opposite value of `value`
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but not what I had initially wanted to do. I was hoping to break the models/collection/model paradigm. I feel that the top level model is a bit redundant. The collection should be smart enough to handle these types of changes.